# Why buffer overflow copying a string?

Tags: c, string

I'm learning C and I don't understand why I get a buffer overflow copying the string.

```
pathValue = getenv("PATH");    
pathlength = strlen(pathValue);
pathValue2 = malloc(sizeof(pathValue));
strncpy(pathValue2, pathValue, pathlength);
```

Can you tell me how it should be done?

Comment: What type is pathValue?

Comment: @rpattiso `char * pathValue;`

Comment: @WebGuy I think that then my answer is good for you. :)

Comment: Your malloc should be malloc(pathlength + 1) then.

Comment: `getenv` may return `NULL`, you need to check the return.

Comment: Please show a MCVE, main and all that gives the buffer overflow, if switching to `pathValue2 = strdup(pathValue)` is still causing issues then there is more to this then the code shown.

Comment: It works with `pathValue2 = strdup(pathValue);`. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can fail for many reasons, like

1. `pathValue` being a pointer, you're not all `malloc()`-ing enough memory to store.
2. `strlen()` won't count the terminating null, so you're missing the same at `pathValue2` while doing `strncpy()` with `pathlength`.

Don't use this approach at all. this `malloc()` + `strncpy()` is the one of the *biggest pitfalls* I have seen.

Instead, learn to use `strdup()`. It's a whole lot better not to get into the trouble by making wrong usage of `strncpy()`.

Comment: Yeah sure - it's also not standard.

Comment: @G.Samaras I guess you're referring to `C` standard, right? AFAIK, `strdup()` is `POSIX` standard.

Comment: In what way `strdup()` is safer than `malloc+str(n)cpy` ?

Comment: @NatashaDutta yes, I think you are guiding the user to the wrong direction.

Comment: @NatashaDutta is right: `strncpy()` is terrible and you don't need it. Never.

Comment: @BlueMoon please [see this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/07/348437.aspx)

Comment: @G.Samaras [believe me, i'm not](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.in/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html). You are free to think otherwise, :-)

Comment: I am talking for `strdup()`.

Comment: That just explains the problem with `strncpy`. It doesn't say how `strdup` is safter than `malloc+str(n)cpy`. `strdup` relies on the string being passed having a `nul` terminator. So it isn't any safer than `malloc+strcpy`.

Comment: @G.Samaras I still don't see your point. only by making use of a `C` standard function how a program get _correct_? the usage is almost always wrong for `strncpy()`.

Comment: @BlueMoon `Safer` in the sense of possibly to misuse. I'll update the wording, if that's causing the issue.

Comment: But I get buffer overflow again using `pathValue2 = strdup(pathvalue);`. I don't understand how I should do this. The underlying problem is that I don't know the length of the array.

Comment: @WebGuy strdup will cause buffer overflow if pathvalue does not point to a NUL terminated string. Try printing it to make sure it looks ok.

Comment: @rpattiso that is not the issue with `strdup()`. `strlen()` will also fail horribly in that case. but frankly speaking, we don't know much about `pathvalue` , do we? :-)

Comment: @NatashaDutta, that's true and it also explains why strdup fails so misusing malloc and strncpy is not the the only issue.

Comment: @rpattiso I never said that's the only issue. I dunno why everybody is deviating from the main issue and running behind the last line of my answer. I've explained the errors(check the timeline :-)) at the very beginning of my answer.

Comment: The value of pathValue is `pathValue = getenv("PATH");` and it looks ok: `$ ./a.out 'PATH' is set to /home/developer/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games.
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./a.out terminated`

Comment: Now it works using `pathValue2 = strdup(pathValue);`. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
pathlength = strlen(pathValue);
pathValue2 = malloc(sizeof(pathValue));
strncpy(pathValue2, pathValue, pathlength);
```

Firstly this:

```
pathValue2 = malloc(sizeof(pathValue));
```

sizeof may or may not be what you're after, we need to see pathValue to be sure. You may mean this:

```
pathValue2 = malloc(strlen(pathValue)+1);
```

Also note the +1, this adds space for the NULL terminator.

Lastly:

```
strncpy(pathValue2, pathValue, pathlength);
```

Just use this:

```
strcpy(pathValue2, pathValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 1 to `pathlength` to account for the null-terminating character at the end of your C-string.

```
pathValue2 = malloc(pathlength + 1);
strncpy(pathValue2, pathValue, pathlength + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I still get buffer overflow using `strncpy(pathValue2, pathValue, pathlength+1);`

Comment: Malloc will need +1 too.

Comment: I don't know what to do since I'm getting buffer overflow even though I follow the answers.